# Laravel 5 config/app.php url setting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This issue became apparent for me when using dynamic routes within scheduled emails. The email url's are built with this config setting which apparently is not setup to adjust to the server environment. I am using Forge for production. What is best practice for configuring this attribute? Would I add a variable to env files?

Currently its set as follow:

```
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use Forge as my production also. Everything works for me.
I have my settings like this :

In my **config\app.php**

I set my `'url' => env('DB_HOST'),`

**DB_HOST** : is just the IP Address to your server.

and that should match with your `.env` file on your Production Server.

My `.env` look something like this :

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_KEY=******************

DB_HOST= http://12.23.29.122/
DB_DATABASE=db-name
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=**************
```

Hope this help !

Comment: Honestly this suggestion is the opposite of how it should be done. **First**, the URL should not rely on the host of the database, as these could be separate pieces of infrastructure. Sure it may be true that the host names are the same, but they are logically different. It would also mean a code change if you do separate DB from web. **Second** your database hostname is not a HTTP URL. You should have separate `APP_URL` and `DB_HOST` entries in the `.env` and the URL entry in `config/app.php` should be based on the `APP_URL` and not `DB_HOST`

Answer (score 3):

If your website will be not installed on other domain, then you can assign it via config file directly:

```
'url' => 'http://localhost',
```

If your application will be installed/ran in different enviroments or domain you can set it via .env file:

```
# .env file
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a number of options

1) set config param on the fly in unit test

```
config(['app.url' => 'https://my.com']);
```

2) configure it in phpunit.xml file once and for all

```
<env name="APP_URL" value="my.com"/>
```

3) change the unittest env on the fly and recreate application in your unit test

$_ENV['APP_URL'] = 'my.com';
   $this->refreshApplication();

4) setup the .env variable in the `public function setUp(): void` of your unit test file before the `parent::setUp();`

5) modifying your .env file is one of the options too

```
APP_URL=my.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem, It's solved for me.

```
1.SET UR APP_URL= yourdomain.com

2.run php artisan config:cache

3.php artisan queue:restart
```

You may write a route for those commands at the live server.

Code at web.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;
Route::get("reboot",function (){
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('queue:restart');
    dd("Ready to Re-start");
});
```